# Big crunch theory

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, space-expansion, reversibility

We study in thermal physics that no natural processes are reversible i. e. they are irreversible, so size of universe, it's also natural process. Why we still say big crunch theory a theory, why can't we just neglect it and say that universe is expanding and will expand forever on the basis of principle I put forward above.
So does means that theory is wrong  or basic principle of thermal physics is wrong  or something else?
I am not so sure so if I said anything wrong about this concept feel free to correct also.

Comment: please read my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581613/do-we-have-equivalent-terminology-of-behaviorism-cognitivism/581686#581686 . Thermal phenomena are emergent from underlying theories, and cosmological theories have to be consistent with  thermodynamics at flat spacetimes and non quantum states, It all depends on hypothesis for curved space times

Answer (score 2):

I think you are assuming that a hypothetical [Big Crunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch) would be like the Big Bang in reverse. This is not correct. Matter and radiation in the early universe had a very uniform distribution, which (due to gravity) was a very improbable state, with low entropy. If the universe were to contract into a Big Crunch then stars and galaxies would first collapse into massive black holes, leading to a state with very high entropy. The final stages would not resemble the Big Bang at all.

We no longer think that the universe is headed towards a Big Crunch, but it is not ruled out because of thermodynamics.

Comment: Can you please explain why it's not ruled out due to thermodynamics? (last 2 lines)

Comment: @KawaljeetKaur Because the final entropy in the Big Crunch is much higher than the initial entropy in the Bug Bang, so the Big Crunch is consistent with the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @gandalf61 how do we know the final entropy at the Big Crunch would be higher? If all matter converges toward a single point then does that not mean there are progressively fewer available quantum states as the universe shrinks? And then at the final moment where everything is compressed to a single point is there not then just one possible quantum state?